# Crystal Reports - Pull Info on Deceased Records and Living Records' Spouses

Tags: crystal-reports, relationship, subreport

I have a report that pulls in deceased executives that are tied to a company. The only parameter is the deceased date. The information is displayed in the Details section so that if they were executives in more than 1 company, both companies are listed. I need to add deceased spouses of the LIVING executives. So if John Doe is CEO of ABC Company and his wife Jane passed away in the parameter's time frame, her name should be listed, not John. I've tried a subreport for the spouses, but it won't work with the information being in the details section. The primary table can't be the death table because we need to pull in the spouses of the LIVING executives. I've thought about having two subpreports - one of the executives and one for the spouses, but I'm not sure how to do that. How would you handle this?

Comment: May you show your schema, your design and sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION ALL View, SP, or Command as the data source for the report.

First Select with regular Company - Exec

UNION ALL

Second Select with Company - Exec - Spouse

If Spouse and Exec are in same table, use that table twice in the 2nd Select and apply an Alias to the 2nd instance.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll work on it and let you know how it goes!